# Count / sum-up weekly work time by calendar category (MS Outlook)

Tags: calendar, outlook, categories, time-management

Is there a way to sum up the time of all meetings for each category (e.g. red) for a specific period of time (e.g. the last week) in Outlook? Thereby, I want to analyze how a spend my time during the week [I assign every single time slot to exactly one category].

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways of achieving it:

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/timespent.htm

1. by using a VBA macro
2. by exporting to Excel and making a report in Excel

Answer (score 0):

There's another option :

To use an application that can gather your Outlook data and provide reports, for instance :

- [TrackingTime](https://trackingtime.co/) : directly connects to Outlook and you can choose which calendar(s) to use, provides reports by calendar and people.
- [Timecamp](https://www.timecamp.com/) : You can import ics files, that'll give you many report options too
- Probably many more, that I haven't tested.